# Hibernate @Where clause inconsistent between HSQL and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

Using hibernate with Mysql and for testing I am using HSQL.
There are many collections where we are using a @Where clause based filtering. For example:

```
@Column(name="CONDITIONS")
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORIES_PKEY")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
@Where(clause="deleted_flag = 'false'")
public List<CategoryConditionMapping> getMappedConditions() {
    return mappedConditions;
}
```

In **MySQL**,

this works:

```
@Where(clause="deleted_flag = 'false'")
```

this doesn't work:

```
@Where(clause="deleted_flag = FALSE")
```

In **HSQL**,

this works:

```
@Where(clause="deleted_flag = FALSE")
```

this doesn't work:

```
@Where(clause="deleted_flag = 'false'")
```

Hsql started supporting @Where(clause="deleted_flag = FALSE"), only after adding custom `HSQLDialect` :

```
public class CustomHSQLDialect extends HSQLDialect {

public CustomHSQLDialect() {
    super();
    registerKeyword("true");
    registerKeyword("false");
    registerKeyword("unknown");
}
}
```

Tried registering for more keywords to this dialect., like

```
    registerKeyword("'false'");
    registerKeyword("'true'");
```

But it doesn't have any effect.
Exception thrown by HSQL, while trying using @Where(clause="deleted_flag = 'false'")

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
>       at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.Scanner.convertToBit(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.types.BitType.castOrConvertToType(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.types.BitType.castToType(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ExpressionOp.getCastExpression(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypesForComparison(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveExpressionTypes(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveTypesPartOne(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)

HSQL is trying to convert string to boolean and fails.

How can we make HSQL understand string 'false' as a bit or how can we make @Where clause generic to work happily on both HSQL and MySQL

Comment: What is the actual property that this annotation is referring to? Is it of type boolean?

Comment: it is annotated on a collection (OneToMany)., but the deleteg_flag is a boolean - which gets evaluated inside the where clause

Comment: Well then the correct form would be deleted_flag = false. How is the database created? Is it auto-generated in both situations, or only when working with HSQL? It might help you to use for example Log4JDBC to see what SQL is specifically being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not using the right type for the column. The best way to use boolean values in MySQL is to use BIT or TINYINT and in the Entity class you define it like 'boolean'. If it doesn't work you should even add @Type like this:

```
@Column(name="DELETED_FLAG")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
public boolean deleted_flag = true;
```

Then hibernate will know what to do with this property. Check this article for mysql data types:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and No., this is not the case. For another comment on my question., I have answered. Now I have updated my question with more details